# Varnish: partical image cache

Tags: caching, varnish

I have a Varnish server that cached images. Some images are cached "partial":

Varnish url:

http://pictures2.todocoleccion.net/tc/2012/07/05/32401624.jpg

Backend url:

http://pictures.todocoleccion.net/tc/2012/07/05/32401624.jpg

The only change I see s that varnish has started to LRU Nuked object, but the "partial" image effect is with new objects.

Any idea about this behaviour? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is nothing about Varnish. It a problem with nginx+cifs server.

Answer (score 0):

I just reloaded the picture in my browser and found the partially fragmented image to display correctly.  Maybe Varnish cached a corrupt image from the backend yesterday?

Comment: I have restarted varnish, so the example image above can display correctly now, but the effect persist with other images. The problem it seems the backend (local nginx with network fs), cause I have changed the backend to another machine (remote nginx with the same fs) and the effect dissapear. Really extrange, need to investigate further.